# Default value for all string properties when source properties are null

Tags: c#, automapper

Is it possible to set all string properties that are null in my source object to some default value within my destination object using AutoMapper?

For example, let's say I had the following two class definitions:

```
public class UniversalForm
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string FaxNumber { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class UniversalFormDto
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string FaxNumber { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Now, MiddleName and FaxNumber are properties that are likely to be null in the UniversalForm class.  So what I would like to be able to do is if FaxNumber or MiddleName are null then in UniversalFormDto object I would like for the value of the corresponding properties to be set to "N/A".

I know this can be accomplished by creating a mapping for each individual member, but I would like to avoid that if at all possible.

I'm looking for a way to define a default value for all my string properties to be used when the corresponding property on my source object (UniversalForm) is null.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a few methods I know:

### ForAllMembers

All null values on all properties will be substituted as `"N/A"`.
Will crash if any of the properties can't be mapped to a string:

```
cfg.CreateMap<UniversalForm, UniversalFormDto>()
.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.NullSubstitute("N/A"));
```

### ForMember

A substitute for every individual property:

```
cfg.CreateMap<UniversalForm, UniversalFormDto>()
.ForMember(dto => dto.FirstName, opt => opt.NullSubstitute("N/A"))
...
;
```

### ConvertUsing

Universal substitute for all `null` strings in any property:

```
cfg.CreateMap<string, string>().ConvertUsing(s => s ?? "N/A");
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if these existed when the question was posted, but I'd suggest using a [Value Transformer](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Value-transformers.html) like this:

```cs
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.ValueTransformers.Add<string>(val => val ?? "N/A");
});
```

or if using profiles:

```cs
public class MyProfile : Profile
{
   public MyProfile()
   {
     ValueTransformers.Add<string>(val => val ?? "N/A");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too familiar with AutoMapper, but after doing some research you may want to try conditional mapping for each property.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Target>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.MiddleName, 
                 opt => opt.MapFrom
                 (src => String.IsNullOrEmpty(src.MiddleName) 
                             ? "N/A" 
                             : src.MiddleName));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your desired default properties in the constructor:

```
public UniversalFormDto() 
{
    FaxNumber = "N/A";
    MiddleName = "N/A";
    //etc...
}
```

Comment: That's probably what I will do if it turns out that AutoMapper can't do what I need it to do.